# What is the difference between a primitive root mod p and a number with period p-1 mod p where p is prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

I am currently studying number theory and have come across the idea that that powers of a primitive root generate all nonzero residues in the field $\mathbb{Z}_p$ but I have also seen numbers with a period of $p-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Aren't these the same thing? If not, how do they differ?

Apologies if my question is trivial, I am struggling to understand this concept.

Comment: Assuming that $n$ in the question is really $p$ (to match the title), then yes, they are two ways of describing exactly the same thing.

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question. Are you working $\bmod p$ or more generally in $\Bbb Z_n$ ?

Comment: @jjagmath apologies, I have corrected this.

Comment: @jjagmath Since you have answered this question perhaps you could clear something else up for me? Why are primitives useful? I get that primitives are group generators and in the case that the modulus is prime the primitive will generate all the non-zero residues but what about in the case when the modulus is not prime?

Comment: Period is not a very useful term here. We usually say they have "multiplicative order" $p-1.$ All numbers have multiplicative "period" $p-1,$ but it isn't the smallest period. But again, we don't use "period" in this context. And yes, elements of order $p-1$ are generators. This isn't true modulo $p^2.$ There are generators of sorts there, too, and they have order $p^2-p.$

Comment: @MrMath a choice of primitive root mod $p$ is used in some cryptosystems (El Gamal), but in math itself, the fact that the nonzero integers mod $p$ have a primitive root is very important when doing finite Fourier analysis because it tells us about the characters of the group of nonzero integers mod $p$: those characters also include a character of order $p-1$.  Ireland and Rosen's book *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory* uses that last fact a lot when they use characters to count solutions of equations over finite fields (finding a main term and an error term in the count).

Comment: $\,a\,$ has order $\,n\!\!\iff\!$ the powers of $\,a\,$ are precisely the $\,n\,$ incongruent elements $\,1,a,a^2,\ldots,a^{n-1}.\ $ But $\,a\,$ is a primitive root $\!\!\iff\!$ the powers include all $\,p\!-\!1\,$ residues $\not\equiv\! 0\!\!\iff\! a\,$ has order $\,n=p-1.\ \ $